# Can we accept that all axioms are equivalent?

Tags: logic

The proposirional logic is based on 3 schema of axioms of which (A1) is
B ⇒ (C ⇒ B). Then, for any 2 axioms p and q, p ⇒ (q ⇒ p) is an instance axiom of (A1). We can have q ⇒ p by a step of MP as we have already p. We can have p ⇒ q in the same manner. So, we have p ⇔ q, that is, all axioms are equivalent. But can we accept this theorem ? If we cannot accept it, for which reason ?

Comment: If $B\implies(C\implies B)$ is an axiom, this somehow *defines* the relation $\implies$, and you need other axioms to get all relevant properties and a definition for $\iff$.

Answer (score 5):

What you have discovered is that any two true propositions are logically equivalent (you do not need them to be axioms in your argument, only that they hold).

What may be confusing is that the truth value of $p \Rightarrow q$ has nothing to do with the *meaning* of $p$ and $q$, it only depends on the truth values of $p$ and $q$. When two statements are logically equivalent, that does *not* say that they have equivalent meanings, only that they have equal truth values.